# Does Python support Default Keyword and Default Variable Length Arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, default-arguments, keyword-argument

I know that Python supports variable arguments `*args` and keyword arguments `**kwargs` but is there a way to have a default for these fields? If not, why?

```
*args = (1,'v')) , **kwargs = {'a':20}
```

I am not saying that I have a use case for this but it seems there is also no reason to disallow this. I do understand that it is trivial to get around this by checking for empty `args`.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: "no reason to disallow this" is more like "there's not enough demand to implement this".

Comment: I agree, but I dont think it is that difficult to implement it, but again I cant think of a use case

Comment: Note that you can submit a pep (with example implementation) if you're willing to have this in some next python version <g>

Comment: @Idlehands: not only is there no demand, there is no need, existing syntax cover the use case described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `*args` and `**kwargs` are the catch-all arguments that receive any arguments for which there are no explicit arguments instead. Specifying defaults defeats their purpose. Instead, your example defaults can be handled with *existing* syntax, there is no need to complicate the function definition syntax here.

You can cover your defaults by specifying *normal keyword arguments*:

```
def foo(pos0, pos1='v', a=20, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

I replaced your `(1, 'v')` 'default' with another keyword argument, because you can provide values for keyword arguments with a *positional* parameter; `foo(42, 'spam')` will set `pos1` to `'spam'`.

In addition, you can always do further processing inside the function you define; the `args` value is a tuple, just test for length to check if you need to use a default for missing values. `kwargs` is a dictionary, just use `kwargs.get(key, default)` or `kwargs.pop(key, default)` or `if key not in kwargs:` or any of the other `dict` methods to handle missing keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can have default `kwargs` and still unpack with `splat` a la `**kwargs`

```
def john(name, dog, *args, bob="bob", **kwargs):
  print(name, dog, bob)

# "ream" is an unpacked arg
john("john", 1, "ream") # john 1 bob

# jane is an unpacked kwarg
john("john", 1, "ream", jane="jane") # john 1 bob

john("john", 1, "ream", bob="jane") # john 1 jane
```

Having a default for an `*arg` is pretty difficult because the idea is to make the function require that input. You could look at some tricks in this vein a la the implementation for the `range` builtin. I would just make it a `kwarg` though.